# Wireless adapter hard blocked: rfkill unblock all not working

Tags: wireless, networking

I did a clean install of ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and now my network adapter seems to be disabled. I get the greyed-out message "Wifi is disabled by hardware switch" When I open the drop-down wifi menu from the top of the screen.

I put in the command `rfkill list wlan` into the terminal, and the following output came up:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I run the command `rfkill unblock all`, and the output from `rfkill list wlan` is exactly the same. I'm starting to think that this has to do with bios settings.

Does anyone have any ideas for my problem?

Comment: The message would indicate that the physical on/off switch of your wifi is turned off.

Answer (score -1):

Try getting the event ID first by running `rfkill event` (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to exit rfkill afterwards).

Then run `rfkill unblock xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx`, replacing `xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx` with the event ID from the previous command.

This will release the block.